# How does Chrome inspector / Firebug magnifier UI works

Tags: google-chrome, firebug

I'm building a Chrome extension that allows users to choose any DOM elements by clicking, like Chrome inspector or Firebug.  To do that, I guess I need to disable all the click events or place transparent mat over the document.   I don't know which way is better, because...

- Disabling(back-up) / Restoring click events seems to be quite complex.
- Using transparent mat over document :  then how can users choose elements by click through the mat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebug code related to this can be found here:

https://github.com/firebug/firebug/blob/master/extension/content/firebug/html/inspector.js

The mouse events are not backed-up and restored. The event is simply [cancelled](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/blob/bf882ad8c0c33253b6ff8f1f9af39434a1a22473/extension/content/firebug/lib/events.js#L146) after it was processed by Firebug.

It indeed overlays the HTML with an element. To get the element under it the Inspector uses the [`originalTarget`](http://help.dottoro.com/ljtagvtt.php). Furthermore it has the CSS property `pointer-events` set to `none`.

Sebastian